# Postgres hot standby WAL history file mssing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I'm trying to create a hot standby. I've replicated the primary with pg_basebackup and configured recovery on the standby however the logs repeatedly show:

```
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/postgresql/15/backup/00000002.history': No such file or directory
LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  restored log file "000000010000BBAC000000CA" from archive
LOG:  contrecord is requested by BBAC/CA000028
```

This is not the latest WAL segment as such the standby is not updating. Is there a way to recover the history file so the standby can continue with WAL recovery?

Many thanks,

Simon

Comment: What is the latest WAL segment? Did you ever delete one of these important history files?

Comment: No information, so no answer possible.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe I didn't delete a history file, the latest WAL segment is far beyond that being reported by the standby. What information would be useful to diagnose further? Are you aware of any recovery approaches?

Comment: Perhaps i wasn't clear enough. What is the file name of a recent WAL segment file? Also, all your recovery parameters are relevant.

Comment: Also, how exactly did you set up replication? If you don't remember exactly, remove the standby and start replication from scratch. There is then little chance to figure out the cause of the problem. The only think that is clear is that there is some corruption in your WAL stream.